# Where is the azimuth and radial direction on the mode plot

Tags: waveguide

Hello the photo bellow presents TE01 mode.
Where on the plot can i see the azimuth and the radial directions?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is completely up to you to define. We can't tell you where you put your horizontal plane, and its normal.

Especially in something as cylindrical as your ... cylinder, it makes little sense to work in a 3D spherical coordinate system, so there's no canonical origin.